# Get logged in members data in http endpoint WIX

Tags: http, backend, velo

I'am trying to implement a http endpoint in the backend of my WIX website. I already implemented the login endpoint that returns the member jwt session token. Also, i created an endpoint that should return this member info but it's always returning Forbidden error. I'am setting the session token as follow: Headers -> Authorization -> {JWT}.

I already tried using the Bearer in the header.

the following code is my http endpoint for login

```
export async function post_loginUser(request) {
const {email,password} = await request.body.json();

try{
    const user = await authentication.login(email, password);

    return ok({...options, body: {user}});
}catch(error){
    return serverError({...options, body: {code: 'Error login the user', error}})
}}
```

This is my endpoint to return the logged in user info.

```
export function get_userInfo() {
const result = currentMember.getMember();

return ok({...options, body: {result}})}
```

And the curl call to the second endpoint:

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://bruno50ramos.wixsite.com/my-site-1/_functions/userInfo' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer JWS.eyJraWQiOiJQSXpvZGJiQiIsImFsZyI6IkhTMjU2In0.eyJkYXRhIjoie1wiaWRcIjpcImZlODMzODAzLTU3NmQtNGMzYy1hNmJmLTEwNjZmMzBlNDlmZFwiLFwiY29sbGVjdGlvbklkXCI6XCJmYTNlYmI3Ni00Nzk2LTQ1MzYtYWJlOS0xMzE2NGNlNWFmZjBcIixcIm1ldGFTaXRlSWRcIjpcImIwZjZmNzMyLTMyMWYtNGVlMC05ODQyLWQyZjE2ZWJhNjhjYVwiLFwib3duZXJcIjpmYWxzZSxcImNyZWF0aW9uVGltZVwiOjE2NDM1NzgxMTM3NzUsXCJleHBpcmVzSW5cIjoxMjA5NjAwMDAwLFwiZXhwaXJhdGlvblRpbWVcIjoxNjQzNTc4MjMzNzc1LFwibGFzdFJlZnJlc2hlZFwiOjAsXCJhZG1pblwiOmZhbHNlfSIsImlhdCI6MTY0MzU3ODExM30.e2g1UDN_Cdxgqx2_8CP369VWIxncqeqaVBFDegoe2xw' \
--header 'Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=1643329893|xgtelcui0Iv-'
```

What I'am doing wrong?

Comment: Try adding the word "Bearer " (with the space) before the token. Also, could you post the code that isn't working?

Comment: Hey @JohnGlenn. I added the examples. Thanks.

Comment: The `JWS.` at the beginning of that token seems out of place to me. Is that right? Does the request work if you delete it?

Comment: Still not working :/

Comment: Would you post your QR code function?

Comment: Hey @JohnGlenn i updated the curl request to the correct function. the function that should return the user info is the `userInfo` with the code above